# VBA Get Values from AutoFilter

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

Let's say I have very large set of data with over 100,000+ rows.  In Column A, I want to find each unique number.

I understand this can be done using the .Find feature and Collections/Arrays but those seem to take a good bit of time - especially with 100,000+ rows.

However, after AutoFiltering Column A, when I hit the down arrow it displays only unique variables.  Is it possible to simply extract those values out of the selections in this way?

```
'pseudocode
filter.Count
Dim X As Long
For x = 2 to filter.Count
   Cells(x, 14) = filter(x)
Next x
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't do that.

Comment: Bummer, thanks for letting me know @Davesexcel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use advanced filter, it's pretty darn quick. I tried it with 127k rows, the results were instant.

```
    Columns("A:A").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("D1"), Unique:=True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the visible cells in to an array. Say your total range (without filter) is `A2:A10000`.  Run your filter, then you can run this macro:

```
Sub t()
Dim arr() As Variant
arr = Range("A2:A10000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    Debug.Print (arr(i, 1))
    ' Do things with each entry in array
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer - this would work if the actual cells were being filtered.  However, I'm trying to reference the values in the filter itself.  I've updated my question for clarity.